# Is there a way to read datavalues from a sheet into an array at index 1 rather than 0?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

I know this sounds trivial, but I am mapping data from one sheet to another, and it would make the human side MUCH easier if the index numbers matched the column numbers in the sheet.  The column mapping gets confusing enough without having to decrement indices by 1. Thx.

Comment: Not worth it....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function useColumnNumberForIndexingArray() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName("name");
  const vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();//if first row is headers
  let hA=vs.shift();
  let colname=[];
  hA.forEach(function(h,i)(colname[h]=i
  let col={};
  for(var i=0;i<sh.getLastColumn();i++) {
    col[i+1]=i;
  }
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    var valueofcolumn1=r[col[1]];//or colname['columnA Name']
    var valueofcolumn2=r[col[2]];//or colname['columnB Name']
  });
}
```

Comment: Should this be a separate post? I tried to just step though the sheet and manually fill the array rather than use Getvalues, so I could control where data went and could start filing in row/col 1.  But the behavior is odd.  As I view the row being pushed on to the array, it is correct, filled with the varying data fro my input file. But the array it is pushed onto seems to change each time a new row is pushed on, all values taking on those of the last row. It's like it's dynamic.  Does this make any sense?

Comment: I played with this for a while and appreciate the code (learned about shift) but it's more than it's worth.  I'll just do the offset from index to actual column.